# How can one configure Context broker to transfer sensor data from FiROS to a database?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

When we use the example tutorials given such as in
https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/time-series-data/index.html

we can perform sending data to Cratedb with no problem. However we are having difficulty to configure FiROS to subscribe to Context broker  and have the Context broker notify CrateDB. Where should we focus in terms of this configuration ? The things to note:

We can see example robot sensor data generated with Gazebo simulator under FiROS
We can send an example manual dummy data via Postman messages directly to CB and perform subscriptions that can be notified to Quantum leap

somehow we can see FiROS gets subscription to CB however we cannot see that is notified to Cratedb via quantum leap

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a strategy for checking this, you can follow the paradigm described in the **Debugging IoT Agents** [Webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRqJsywi9e8) - it describes a scenario using MQTT topics rather than ROS, but the strategy is much the same.

1. Maximise your debug for all components - FIROS, Context Broker, QuantumLeap
2. Test sending a dummy measure direct into the Context Broker and check that it has arrived - this open issues around your containerization strategy (e.g. misuse of `localhost`)
3. Once you are able to send dummy messages directly, create the subscription and check that it is firing - this checks that the subscription is broad enough
4. Check that the subscription is being received properly - QuantumLeap could be misconfigured. Check the subscription for `lastSuccess` and failure
5. Briefly make a call to the QuantumLeap endpoints to check that data is received in the right format (e.g. make a `lastN` call or check the database directly.
6. At this point you can start connecting FIROS, ensure the appropriate topics are being monitored and check the logs.

This strategy should narrow down where in the chain of events the break is occurring and give you debug to work out what is going wrong. If necessary you could post some debug here on StackOverflow to give the community a chance to respond (at the moment it is impossible to tell where your system is breaking)

If the problem can be narrowed down to a single component, you could also consider raising an issue on the appropriate GitHub repository - e.g. [FIROS](https://github.com/iml130/firos) or [FIROS2](https://github.com/eProsima/FIROS2)